# fetch method returns data from previous api call

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch

I'm trying to fetch data based on user selection.
The first API call (getLocationForUser) works fine and returns the right values. However, right after the user selects the location, I'm trying to make another API call (getRoomForUser) to a different endpoint but it keeps loading the data from the getLocationForUser cal.

- I was trying to use the fetch function and also with sync-request.
- I was testing the getRoomForUser API only and it returns the expected data

  ```
  switch (userSelection) {
    case 'puerto rico':
      await this.getLocationForUser(currentEmployee);
      break;
    case 'user set a location':
      await this.getRoomForUser(context)
      break;
    case 'user set a room':
      await this.setAttendance(context)
      break;
    default:
  }

  async getLocationForUser(currentEmployee){
    let getLocations = "https://sampleGetLocations.com";

    fetch( getLocations,
    {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
      Authorization: 'auto dfgasdg'
      }
    })
  .then(response =>
      response.json()
  )
  .then(json => {
      data1.push(json.outPutSite[0].value)
  });

  return data1;
  }

  async getRoomForUser(currentEmployee){
    let getRooms = "https://sampleGetRoomForUser.com";

    fetch( getRooms,
    {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
          Authorization: 'auto dfgasdg'
      }
    })
    .then(response =>
        response.json()
    )
    .then(json => {
        data2.push(json.outPutSite[0].value)
    });
    return data2;
  }
  ```

Actual result:
Both **getLocationForUser** and **getRoomForUser** return the data from **getLocationForUser**

Expected result:
Each of the API calls **getLocationForUser** and **getRoomForUser** return **relevant data**

Comment: Did you intentionally leave out a `break;` statement after the "puerto rico" `case` in the `switch`?

Comment: No, sorry, I will add it now

Comment: What do you mean @randomSoul

Comment: @Peter - I'am sorry, that is one liner code. so explicit `return` is not required.

Comment: Even when I put return data2.push(json.outPutSite[0].value) I'm still getting the data of getLocationForUser